# What are the Steps of Database Design/Data Modeling

Tags: database

From my understanding, the process of database design is as follows:

1. Determine the Purpose of the Database (Requirement Analysis)
2. Gather data, organize in tables, and specify the primary key
3. Normalize Data
4. Create relationships among tables

The process of data modeling would then be:

1. Translate design into a conceptual model
2. Translate conceptual model into a logical model
3. Translate logical model into a physical model

Is there anything I am missing or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have mentioned is very general and of course step 1 before you start designing anything.

But first thing, what are your data sources? How you are gonna record data? is it API calls, triggers and etc?

considering your tech stack and the scope of your project and of course what you want to do with in future, you can determine what kind of database is a fit for you. Relational, NoSql, or even if you need hadoop based version of either of those.

Then it comes to tables, relations, indexes and etc. The goal should be accessing your desired data fast and easy.

There are many DBA techniques that again depend on your tech stack you can read.

You need to be more specific when you ask such questions.